# Adding a homebrew dependency to an npm package

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, homebrew

I am wanting to add a homebrew dependency to an npm package I am trying to create, I am using drafter-HEAD. Does anyone have an ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things to come to mind. You could point the dependency to the GitHub repo if it has one.

```js
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Description Here",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "The Best Developer Ever",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express" : "github:expressjs/express",
    "anyRepo" : "github:userName/projectName"
  }
}
```

you could also make a custom command in your `package.json` file. Call it maybe brew (*this is different from the actual command line tool*) and you would run your scripts there

```js
{
  "name": "my-project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Description Here",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "brew" : "sudo brew install package-name(s)-here",
    "any-name-here" : "echo Any command can go here"
  },
  "author": "The Best Developer Ever",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express" : "github:expressjs/express",
  }
}
```

then after you would run

> `npm run brew`

And any script inside of that command will run (aka install the homebrew dependency). This should be what you are looking for, I believe.

-- juan

**EDIT** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sorry, I accidentally gave the wrong command. You should run `npm run brew` **NOT** `npm brew`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Brewfile` to specify dependencies installed via Homebrew and the `brew bundle` command to install dependencies. The `Brewfile` is similar to your `package.json`, it's a manifest of your dependencies. This will be easier to read and maintain compared to specifying a list of arguments in an npm script. Additionally you'll get other benefits of a package manager such as the generation of a *lockfile* (`Brewfile.lock.json`), although Homebrew's lockfile behaves differently from a typical lockfile ([reference](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle/pull/552)).

#### Further reading

- [Homebrew documentation on the `brew bundle` command](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#bundle-subcommand)
- [GitHub repository for `homebrew-bundle`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle)